# Getting Error "read ECONNRESET" in Bot Framework

Tags: visual-studio, botframework, azure-bot-service

I am getting this `'ServiceError'` when I am running my Bot from Visual Studio. It is showing..

```
code:"ServiceError"

message:"request to http://localhost:3978/api/messages failed, reason: read ECONNRESET"
```

Can anyone please help me to fix this issue? I tried changing port number also but facing the same issue.

[image]

Comment: Hi, what operating system are you using?

Comment: are you getting this error in terminal or emulator?

Comment: emulator and operating system windows 10

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved with two different ways:

1. Try to make sure to run the bot before trying to connect with emulator
2. Some cases it is because of the `IISExpress configuration` of `IPv4` of port listings. IPv4 is not listing `127.0.0.1` with post `3978`. Instead change from `IISExpress to AspNetCore.Hosting`